# How can I dynamically determine the height of a jquery ui dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, vertical-scrolling

I am displaying a jquery UI dialog with a lot of content and I don't want the dialog height larger than the vertical parent window.  For now I have been just hardcoding height to be 740

```
$("#myDialogContainer").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 740,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 1065,
    modal: true
```

but for people with large monitors this "cutoff" is unnecessary. If I do auto then its too long vertically with people with small monitors, laptops, etc.

How can I set the height to always fit within the parent window and scroll if its larger but don't scroll if not required?

Comment: Why don't you style the height of the UI dialog with CSS, based on ID and leave the `height` property to be handled by jQuery automatically?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying? can you illustrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this!

```
$(function() {
var maxHeight = $(window).height();
$(window).resize(function(){
    maxHeight = $(this).height();
    $( "#myDialogContainer" ).dialog( "option", "height", maxHeight );
}); 
$( "#myDialogContainer" ).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height: maxHeight,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Delete all items": function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```

});